# Flutter - Adding Container (widget) in GridView when click a button?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I wanted to add a container widget in the GridView when a button is clicked. I was able to do this with the column widget but could not do it with GridView.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

List<Widget> gridChild = [
  Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    width: 30.0,
    height: 50.0,
    color: Colors.green,
  ),
  Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    width: 30.0,
    height: 50.0,
    color: Colors.green,
  ),
  Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    width: 30.0,
    height: 50.0,
    color: Colors.green,
  ),
  Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    width: 30.0,
    height: 50.0,
    color: Colors.green,
  ),
  Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    width: 30.0,
    height: 50.0,
    color: Colors.green,
  ),
];

class Grid extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GridState createState() => _GridState();
}

class _GridState extends State<Grid> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            gridChild.add(Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              width: 30.0,
              height: 50.0,
              color: Colors.green,
            ));
            print(gridChild.length);
          });
        },
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: gridChild,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What I did was that I added a container in the widget list. The length of the list increases as I click the botton but the container was not added on the screen. It didn't work even though I put the function inside the setState().

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works...

```
class Grid extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GridState createState() => _GridState();
}

class _GridState extends State<Grid> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            gridChild.add(Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              width: 30.0,
              height: 50.0,
              color: Colors.green,
            ));
          });
        },
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: List.generate(gridChild.length, (index) => gridChild[index]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: why need `List.generate` to copy the list ??

Answer (score 0):

Use **GridView.builder** in the body. It should fix your problem. I don't really know why, but I know it works. Hopefully someone can update this answer and provide an explanation.

```
GridView.builder(
        itemCount: gridChild.length,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
          return gridChild[index];
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by calling the setstate method.

while clicking on the button just add a widget to the list and use the setstate after adding to the list. Basically setstate will rebuild the screen.